# Javascript adding a leading zero to all single digit numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, string

```
var string = "name t13 - cat y4 - dat s6";
```

should be changed to "name t13 - cat y04 - dat s06"

I need the string to always have at least two digit numbers.  How can I change numbers within a string to lead with a zero if there is a single digit?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about us doing your work for you.

Comment: Use objects to hold these values. Hyphens are not made for separation of concerns.

Comment: Are `cat` and `dat` fixed?

Comment: If your only use case is adding a leading zero to single-digit numbers, that can easily be done with a quick&dirt regex search/replace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex: find one-digit number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099150/regex-find-one-digit-number)

Comment: @TravisJ the string is part of loop that always changes. So it could be: 

`var string = "name t13 - cat y4 - dat s6";` or `var string = "others13y4sixs6";`

Either way the single digits need a leading zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.prototype.replace()` accepts a regular expression as the first argument for pattern matching. You can also supply a function as the second argument which is called for each match and returns a replacement value.

```js
var tests = [
    "s61 t1 e32 w2 i5 e600",
    "name t13 - cat y4 - dat s6",
    "others13y4sixs6"
];

tests.forEach(function(test){
    console.log(test.replace(/\D\d(?!\d+)/g, function(c) { 
        return c.charAt(0) + "0" + c.charAt(1); 
    }));
});
```

Comment: I needed this to work for characters at the start of the string as well so I had to change the function to this: `console.log(test.replace(/(^|\D)\d(?!\d+)/g, function(c) { if(c.length == 1) {return "0" + c.charAt(0);}else {return c.charAt(0) + "0" + c.charAt(1); }}));`