# rename numbers in files

Tags: powershell, formatting, numbers, batch-rename

I want to rename only `.csv` files which do not conform to name format guidelines. All other files with incorrect numbers are ok.

correct:

```
     31_12_99-01.csv
     01_01_00-88.csv
```

incorrect:

```
     2_1_00-01.csv
```

I need help to identify numbers smaller than 10 (only one digit).

```
Get-ChildItem *.csv -Name |Where{$_.Name -match '\d+'}
```

After rename powershell should show all renamed files(new file name) so I can choose to save this list to `rename.cfg`.

Comment: Hmm, at least this will list the problem ones.  `Get-ChildItem *.csv  | Where {$_.Name -match '[^\d]\d[^\d]'}`

Comment: I'd like to see what someone else comes up with.  This is a nice site to try out regex:  https://regex101.com/.  I don't know why this doesn't match both single numbers:  `'2_1_00-01.csv' -match '(\b|_)\d_'; $matches`.

Answer (score 0):

```
get-childitem *.csv |
where name -match '(\b|_)\d_' |
rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '(\b)(\d_)','${1}0$2' -replace '(_)(\d_)','${1}0$2' } -whatif -passthru

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Users\js\foo\2_1_00-01.csv Destination: C:\Users\js\foo\02_01_00-01.csv".

# why doesn't this work?  I guess because the patterns overlap
# rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '(\b|_)(\d_)','${1}0$2' } -whatif -passthru
```

EDIT:  With negative lookbehind and negative lookahead, sweet.  [regex: find one-digit number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099150/regex-find-one-digit-number)

```
get-childitem *.csv |
where name -match '(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)' |
rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '(?<!\d)(\d)(?!\d)','0$1' } -whatif -passthru
```